# How to count the row frequency

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the simplest way to simplify the first two columns of the a data, so that each row is counted to with a new variable freq?

In other words, go from this:

```
   var1 var2
1    a    d
2    b    e
3    b    e
4    c    f
5    c    f
6    c    f
```

To this:

```
   var1 var2 freq
1    a    d    1
2    b    e    2
3    c    f    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably did not take a close look with `dplyr` package ( You tagged it :) ). The easiest way is below ...

```
df <-data.frame(freq1 = c("a","b","b","c","c","c"),
                freq2 = c("d","e","e","f","f","f"))
df %>% group_by(freq1,freq2) %>% tally()
```

Output

```
   freq1  freq2     n
  (fctr) (fctr) (int)
1      a      d     1
2      b      e     2
3      c      f     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the is the easiest, but if the data isnt that complex you can create unique codes using a `paste0(collapse="_")` and then aggregate by that unique code using a simple `table` command

```
data<-read.csv("data.csv")

x<-apply(data,1,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = "_"))

table(x)
```

Comment: Consider making your solution more robust to handle non-perfect arrangements as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use the `dplyr` package's `count` function, an alternative is to use the contingency tables generated by the `ftable` function and filter out contingencies with 0 occurrences. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(freq1 = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                 freq2 = c("d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "f"))
x <- as.data.frame(ftable(df))
x <- x[x$Freq > 0, ]
```

This yields the output:

```
  freq1 freq2 Freq
1     a     d    1
5     b     e    2
9     c     f    3
```